# Computing number of new IDs seen each day in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following data, of which users were active each day, I would like to compute the number of new users for each day, using Pandas.

```
Data:
  Day | UserID
  ----------
   1  |  A 
   1  |  B
   1  |  C
   1  |  C
   ----------
   2  |  A 
   2  |  B
   2  |  D
   2  |  A 
   2  |  E
  ----------
   3  |  B 
   3  |  D
   3  |  F

Result:    
  Day | New Users
  ---------------
   1  |  3
   2  |  2
   3  |  1
```

The way I see it, the steps are:

1. Compute the max UserID per day:  ***df.groupby('Day').UserID.max()***
2. Filter the data with the max UserID of the previous day (initialize at 0): ***here I have no clue how to do this using Pandas***
3. Compute the number of signs in from unique users over the filtered data set. ***df.filtered.groupby('Day').UserID.nunique()***

Is there a clean way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This build as a table giving the day each ID is first seen, groups by the day, and then counts the corresponding rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(1, "A"), (1, "B"), 
                   (1, "C"), (1, "C"), 
                   (2, "A"), (2, "B"), 
                   (2, "D"), (2, "A"), 
                   (2, "E"), (3, "B"), 
                   (3, "D"), (3, "F")], 
                  columns=["day", "userid"]) 

(df
  .sort_values('day')
  .groupby('userid')
  .first()
  .rename(columns={"day": "first_seen"})
  .groupby('first_seen').size()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dataframe is first sorted by `Day`, you can group on `UserID` (setting `as_index=False`) and then set the index of the result to `Day`.  This gives you each new user on each day.

```
df2 = df.groupby('UserID', as_index=False).Day.first().set_index('Day') 
>>> df2
    UserID
Day       
1        A
1        B
1        C
2        D
2        E
3        F
```

To then get the total number of new users:

```
>>> df2.groupby(level=0).UserID.count()
Day
1    3
2    2
3    1
Name: UserID, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

An efficient approach (that does not rely on `groupby`) would be to keep only the first occurrence of each UserID by running [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by UserID on the dataset sorted by Day, then to count the users per day with [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
out = (df
       .sort_values(by='Day') # only if not already sorted
       .drop_duplicates(subset='UserID')
       ['Day'].value_counts()
       .reset_index(name='New Users')
       )
```

Output:

```
   Day  New Users
0    1          3
1    2          2
2    3          1
```